# Error While Uploading a file in zend framework2

Tags: file-upload, zend-framework2, adapter

I have created a form with a file upload fields and tried to upload the file as follows:

```
    $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Transfer();
    $adapter->addValidator(‘Count’,false, array(‘min’=>1, ‘max’=>3))
    ->addValidator(‘Size’,false,array(‘max’ => 10000))
    ->addValidator(‘Extension’,false,array(‘extension’ => ‘txt’,’case’ => true));

    $adapter->setDestination('images/');

    $files = $adapter->getFileInfo();

    foreach($files as $fieldname=>$fileinfo)
    {
    if (($adapter->isUploaded($fileinfo[name]))&& ($adapter->isValid($fileinfo[‘name’])))
    {
    $adapter->receive($fileinfo[name]);
    //then, store links etc in db for retrieval later..
    }

    }
    var_dump($adapter->getMessages());
```

and i have got the error:

```
Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\ValidatorPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for ‘Count’
```

How i can solve this and make it workable?

Comment: @Dymen1 do you have any solution for this?

Comment: When do you receive this error message? When the adapter is created or when a file is uploaded?

Comment: when the file is uploaded it generate this error and do not upload the file

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code. First of all
`new \Zend\File\Transfer\Transfer();` is not an adapter but a transfer adapter manager.

You shouldn't name your variable with this. Let's correct and explain.

```
    //We initialize the transfer adapter manager
    $transferService = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Transfer();
    //We fetch the matching adapter
    //the doc says that the param is to be set to true to fetch upload adapter, false for download adapter, null for both.
    //For us it's true
    $adapter = $transferService->getAdapter(true);

    //Now the rest should be working fine

    $adapter->addValidator(‘Count’,false, array(‘min’=>1, ‘max’=>3))
    ->addValidator(‘Size’,false,array(‘max’ => 10000))
    ->addValidator(‘Extension’,false,array(‘extension’ => ‘txt’,’case’ => true));

    $adapter->setDestination('images/');

    $files = $adapter->getFileInfo();

    foreach($files as $fieldname=>$fileinfo)
    {
    if (($adapter->isUploaded($fileinfo[name]))&& ($adapter->isValid($fileinfo[‘name’])))
    {
    $adapter->receive($fileinfo[name]);
    //then, store links etc in db for retrieval later..
    }

    }
    var_dump($adapter->getMessages());
```

Since the documentation is not really complete on this subject, you really should dig in the code and see how it's done. It's really quick to understand.

Hope this helped

Comment: Call to a member function addValidator() on null.. @Unex

Comment: depending on your version of zf2. You may keep your script and just change `    $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Transfer();` to `$adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer();`